# Docker compose volume syntax valid for Windows and Linux

Tags: docker-compose, linux, windows, environment-variables, volume

We have developers working on an app using both Windows and Linux. The application is built within a Docker container, and ships a docker-compose specification for the build environment.

The local directory is mounted as a volume:

```
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}:/tmp
```

however **this doesn't work in Windows** because `$PWD` is not defined.

My question is:

**Can we have a single `docker-compose.yml` to satisfy both the Windows and Linux developers?**

The obvious way to do this seems to me to have two docker-compose files, one for each OS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  Just use ./ for you current directory that the Docker-compose file is in. Your "working directory" for the compose file is just "./".  If you are trying to set a directory below that it would look something like:

```
volumes:
```

- ./DirectoryIWantToTarget:/tmp

There's an example of this in the Docker-Compose documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3).  This approach makes the solution cross-platform as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
PS C:\Users\gaius> Write-Output $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  592     



PS C:\Users\gaius> Write-Output $pwd

Path          
----          
C:\Users\gaius
```

That appears to work as expected, what versions of things are you using?

Compare to Linux:

```
gaius@klossy:~$ pwsh
PowerShell 6.2.2
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/gaius> echo $pwd

Path
----
/home/gaius

PS /home/gaius>
```

(`echo` is just an alias for `Write-Output`)

If you must have exact commonality between Windows and Linux there are a few solutions, Git comes with Bash for Windows, there's WSL, etc.

Comment: This answer makes me look like a bit of an idiot :)  -- and certainly show the gaps in my PowerShell knowledge. The developer claimed that `${PWD}` wasn't working for them Unfortunately, I have no way of verifying this, not having access to a Windows machine. But certainly it looks like it should work (I'm using Powershell 6.2.2 on Linux)

Comment: @BruceBecker added the Linux to my answer

Comment: Actually now that I think about it some more, just recommend your Windows devs use Git Bash if they absolutely must do things the same way as Linux

Answer (score 2):

I think my case may be related as I also tried to configure environment for both Windows and Linux. I only have to mention that I am using `docker-compose` on WSL1 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) configured following by: [this](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly)

I suggest you to try

My solution is (using the: [long-syntax volumes definition](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3) from official docs):

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./DirectoryWithDockerfile
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./DirectoryIWantToMountInDockerContainer
        target: /path/where/mount/source
        volume:
          nocopy: true  # flag to disable copying of data from a container when a volume is created
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

I don't know why short syntax doesn't worked on Windows for me (and for you):

```
   volumes:  # this doesn't work and I don't know why
     - ./DirectoryIWantToMountInDockerContainer/:/path/where/mount/source
```

My Docker version: 19.03.5

docker-compose version: 1.25.4

Answer (score 0):

```
volumes:
  - /usr/local/db-backup:/var/lib/mysql # On Linux, For backup data from the docker container to the host
  - D:/Docker_volumes/mysql/db-backup:/var/lib/mysql # On Windows, you need to config File Sharing with "D:" mounted when starting docker.
```

Comment: Welcome to DevOps.  Thanks for your contribution.  You've shown how to do a volume in each Linux and Windows, but not how the OP could have one `docker-compose.yml` which works for both.

Answer (score 0):

2022 update
If you want to have a persistent database for docker(Windows) MySQL using docker Hyper-V

1. Make a folder at any location where you want to have your DB data
   for eg. D:\DockerDB
2. Now, use Docker in Hyper-v mode.
3. Go to settings -> Resources -> File sharing -> add you DB data folder here.(D:\DockerDB) and apply and restart.
   [image]

In your docker-compose.yml file add volumes as below

```
mysqldb:
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - D:/DockerDB:/var/lib/mysql
```

Now your data will persist on DB on your local machine.